# Connect to Power BI XMLA endpoint of dataset using Python

Tags: python, powerbi, xmla

Is there a library to connect to a dataset using Python. I have uploaded blob as dataset in Powerbi. I want to access that dataset using XMLA endpoint. I tried using adodbapi  but it isn't showing the tables I want.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLA endpoints can be used with MSOLAP and ADOMD client libraries, i.e. you can use something like [olapy](https://pypi.org/project/olapy/) or [pyadomd](https://pypi.org/project/pyadomd/).

Comment: If possible could you provide me with some python code of your implementation?